# Error Cannot read property 'updaterCacheDirName' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, electron, electron-builder, electron-updater

I'm trying to create an application with auto update, but I have an error when running the version search

the app finds the version and when it is about to go down I get this error

```
Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'updaterCacheDirName' of undefined
    at NsisUpdater.getOrCreateDownloadHelper (C:\Users\neyun\Desktop\app\node_modules\electron-updater\out\AppUpdater.js:659:55)
    at async NsisUpdater.executeDownload (C:\Users\neyun\Desktop\app\node_modules\electron-updater\out\AppUpdater.js:708:36)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'updaterCacheDirName' of undefined
    at NsisUpdater.getOrCreateDownloadHelper (C:\Users\neyun\Desktop\app\node_modules\electron-updater\out\AppUpdater.js:659:55)
    at async NsisUpdater.executeDownload (C:\Users\neyun\Desktop\app\node_modules\electron-updater\out\AppUpdater.js:708:36)
```

I already checked my code where it does the function of updating and I checked it with other codes in repositories in Github but all are equal to the one I have this is my code in an app menu

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
          const { autoUpdater } = require("electron-updater");
          let token = "";
          let v = app.getVersion()
          autoUpdater.allowPrerelease = true;
          autoUpdater.currentVersion = v;
          autoUpdater.logger = log;
          autoUpdater.autoDownload = false
          autoUpdater.setFeedURL({
            "provider": "github",
            "owner": "",
            //"token": token, //deleted 
            "private":true,
            "repo": ""
          });
          autoUpdater.logger.transports.file.level = 'info';
          log.info('App starting...');
          function createWindow () {
            mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
              width: 800,
              height: 600,
              webPreferences: {
                nodeIntegration: true,
              },
            });
            mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/public/update.html`);
            mainWindow.setMenu(null)
            mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
              mainWindow = null;
            });
            autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();



          }


          createWindow();



          app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
            if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
              app.quit();
            }
          });

          app.on('activate', function () {
            if (mainWindow === null) {
              createWindow();
            }
          });

          ipcMain.on('app_version', (event) => {
            event.sender.send('app_version', { version: app.getVersion() });
          });

          autoUpdater.on('update-available', () => {
            mainWindow.webContents.send('update_available');
            autoUpdater.downloadUpdate().then((path)=>{
              console.log('download path', path)
            }).catch((e)=>{
              console.log(e)
            })
          });

          autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', () => {
            autoUpdater.autoInstallOnAppQuit()
          });
          autoUpdater.on('checking-for-update', () => {
            mainWindow.webContents.send('check_update');
          });
          autoUpdater.on('update-not-available', () => {
            mainWindow.webContents.send('not_update');
          });
          ipcMain.on('restart_app', () => {


          });
```

and this is the html where both the version and a warning are shown whether or not there is a new version

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Update</title>
  <style>
    body {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 20px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      background-color: #eaeaea;
      text-align: center;
    }
    #notification {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 20px;
      left: 20px;
      width: 200px;
      padding: 20px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: white;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
    .hidden {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>app</h1>
  <span><p>Version:</p> <p id="version"></p></span>
  <div id="notification" class="hidden">
    <p id="message"></p>

    <button id="close-button" onClick="closeNotification()">
      Close
    </button>
    <button id="restart-button" onClick="restartApp()" class="hidden">
      Restart
    </button>
  </div>
  <script>
    const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
    const version = document.getElementById('version');
    const notification = document.getElementById('notification');
    const message = document.getElementById('message');
    const restartButton = document.getElementById('restart-button');

    ipcRenderer.send('app_version');
    ipcRenderer.on('app_version', (event, arg) => {
      ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners('app_version');
      version.innerText = 'Version ' + arg.version;
    });
    ipcRenderer.on('update_available', () => {
      ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners('update_available');
      message.innerText = 'A new update is available. Downloading now...';
      notification.classList.remove('hidden');
    });
    ipcRenderer.on('check_update', () => {
      ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners('check_update');
      message.innerText = 'Looking for update...';
      notification.classList.remove('hidden');
    });
    ipcRenderer.on('not_update', () => {
      ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners('not_update');
      message.innerText = 'update not available...';
      notification.classList.remove('hidden');
    });
    ipcRenderer.on('update_downloaded', () => {
      ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners('update_downloaded');
      message.innerText = 'Update Downloaded. It will be installed on restart. Restart now?';
      restartButton.classList.remove('hidden');
      notification.classList.remove('hidden');
    });
    function closeNotification() {
      notification.classList.add('hidden');
    }

    function restartApp() {
      ipcRenderer.send('restart_app');
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you test the auto update function in your develop mode, whithout packaging the application?

I had the same error and the following solution worked for me.

Take a look at the [documentation](https://www.electron.build/auto-update):

> Note that in order to develop/test UI/UX of updating without packaging the application you need to have a file named dev-app-update.yml

In this case create an "dev-app-update.yml" file in your root directory and provide your publish properties from your package.json in yaml format.

**dev-app-update.yml**

```
provider:"github"
owner: "abc"
```